# Why the code below does not outputs correctly for all test cases?

Tags: c, string, loops, ide, codeblocks

```
/*
*
*Program for finding total number of holes in a string.
*For example total number of holes in "ANUBHAV" is 4 and in "GOURAV" is 3
*
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
// start of main function
int main(void) {
    int t,i = 0,hole = 0; // variable declaration
`   char str[100];
    scanf("%d",&t); // input number of test cases
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%s",str);  // input string
        while(i < strlen(str))
        {
            if(str[i] == 'B')
            {
                hole += 2;
            }
            else if(str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'D' || str[i] == 'O' || str[i] == 'P' || str[i] == 'Q' || str[i] == 'R' )
            {
                hole += 1;
            }

            i = i + 1;  
        }
        printf("%d",hole); //printing the total number of holes
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs correctly in the first test case(t), But produces wrong   output for next test cases. What is the problem in the code? 
Please Help!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Could be because you have a stray backtick in your `main` function...

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `hole` every time a new string is input. Your code also can be improved a lot, check this

```
/*
*
*Program for finding total number of holes in a string.
*For example total number of holes in "ANUBHAV" is 4 and in "GOURAV" is 3
*
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// start of main function
int main(void)
{
    int hole; // variable declaration
    int count;
    char str[100];
    if (scanf("%d", &count) != 1)
        return -1; // Input Error
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        hole = 0;
        if (scanf("%99s", str) != 1)
            return -1; // Input Error
        for (int j = 0 ; str[j] != '\0' ; ++j)
        {
            switch (str[j])
            {
                case 'B':
                    hole += 2;
                    break;
                case 'A':
                case 'D':
                case 'O':
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                    hole += 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("Holes in %s -> %d\n", str, hole); //printing the total number of holes
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:-**

In your code, you should initialize `hole` inside the loop,

```
while (t--) {
int hole = 0;
.
.
}
```

**Explanation:-**

The count of `hole` is distinctive for each test case. If it is not initialized at `0` for each test case, the count shown will add up previous count, resulting in an erroneous result.

For example, if *test_case_0* had 2 holes, hole is set to `2` then, if *test_case_1* had `3` holes, and hole is not reset to `0`, the final result will be hole set to `5` for *test_case_1*, which is causing the error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should  have to make value of hole=0 inside while statement and after printf function.Because your hole value does not change for next test case.